# Prove the NP-hardness of problem

Tags: complexity-theory, np-hard

Prove the $NP$-hardness of $CONNECTEDNESS$ - the problem of counting over an oriented graph $G$ and two vertices
$s$ and $t$ the number of subgraphs of $G$ in which from $s$ to $t$ can be traversed by an oriented path. Does the corresponding problem of recognition in $P$? If necessary, one can use the $NP$-hardness of the problem of calculating the permutation of a matrix.

I'm doing a problem-solving book for a foreign language problem book, and would appreciate your help:)

Comment: We're not particularly looking for posts that are just the statement of an exercise-style task.  What did you try? Where did you get stuck? We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: Where did you encounter this task?  Can you credit the original source?  Note that we require you to credit the original source of all copied material: https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Answer (score 0):

This problem is called $s$-$t$ $\texttt{NODE CONNECTEDNESS}$ and was proved to be $\#\mathsf{P}$-complete by Valiant in 1979 in *The Complexity of Enumeration and Reliability Problems*.

As such, it is $\mathsf{NP}$-hard: if it could be solved in polynomial time, you could solve $\#\texttt{SAT}$ in polynomial time, and then solve $\texttt{SAT}$ in polynomial time.

However, the corresponding decision problem, deciding if there exists a path from $s$ to $t$, is in $\mathsf{P}$ (in fact, it is even $\mathsf{NL}$-complete). That is not contradictory as there are other examples: for example, $\#2\texttt{SAT}$ is $\#\mathsf{P}$-complete, but its decision version is in $\mathsf{P}$.